# Is Horner's method for the evaluation of derivatives of polynomials unnecessarily complicated?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

I do understand Horner's method and I understand how it can be used to efficiently evaluate a polynomial

$$p_n(x) = a_nx^n+...,a_1x+a_0 $$

at $x = x_0$ using only $n$ multiplications. This results in a polynomial $q_{n-1}$ of degree $n-1$ (whose coefficients depend on $x_0$) such that

$$ p_n(x) = (x-x_0)q_{n-1}(x) + p_n(x_0).$$

One can then observe, that

$$ p_n^{\prime}(x_0) = q_{n-1}(x_0) $$

and again apply Horner's method, this time to evaluate $q_{n-1}(x_0)$, in order to find $p_n^{\prime}(x_0)$.

This is frequently done when applying Horner's method to make Newton's root finding algorithm more efficient.

I do not see however, why this way of computing $p_n^{\prime}(x_0)$ via $q_n$ is in any way better than just computing the general derivative function $p_n^{\prime}(x)$ and then use Horner's method to evaluate $p_n^{\prime}(x_0)$.

Why do we make a detour and use the polynomial $q_{n-1}$ ( which results from our application of Horner's method to evaluate $p_n(x_0)$) to compute $p_n^{\prime}(x_0)$ instead of computing it "directly",  by determining $p_n^{\prime}(x)$ and then using Horner's method to evaluate $p_n^{\prime}(x_0)$?

Comment: Who says "we" don't?

Comment: Do you? ;-)

I have seen this in several lecture notes and assume there must be a reason for this seemingly more complicated approach, perhaps a numerical one.

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Divided_difference_of_a_polynomial) is the original form. And even for the derivative case, there are some tiny savings (no need to compute/keep the coefficients of the derivative).

Comment: But, when, for example, using Horner's method in the context of the Newton-Rapson algorithm, the cost of computing the derivative coefficients seems negligible since this has to be done only once (rather than on every iteration), so this does not seem to justify the extra complication for me tbh.